# Is it possible to get nested tuples from "security" function?

Tags: pine-script

In pine script's security function, we can pass a tuple as an argument so we can get a tuple as result and this will reduce security method call:

```
[dayClose, CustomFunctionResult] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [close, yourCustomFunction()])
```

This syntax is correct, but if the custom function returns a tuple too (e.g. MACD) we will get a syntax error:

```
[dayClose, [line, signal, hist]] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [close, macd(12, 26, 9)])
```

And this doesn't work either:

```
[dayClose, line, signal, hist] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [close, macd(12 ,26 ,9)])
```

We can write 3 custom MACD functions and break the result into 3 separate function calls (each returning a single variable):

```
[dayClose, line, signal, hist] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [close, macdLine(12 ,26 ,9), macdSignal(12 ,26 ,9), macdhist(12 ,26 ,9)])
```

This works but it's not a pleasant solution.
Is it even possible to get a nested tuple as result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not supported, afaik. You could hack a combo:

```
//@version=4
study("")
f_combo(_source, _fastlen, _slowlen, _siglen) =>
    [_macdLine, _signalLine, _histLine] = macd(_source, _fastlen, _slowlen, _siglen)
    [close, _macdLine, _signalLine, _histLine]

[c, macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", f_combo(close, 12, 26, 9))
plot(macdLine, color=color.blue)
plot(signalLine, color=color.orange)
plot(histLine, color=color.red, style=plot.style_histogram)
plotchar(c, "c", "", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

Comment: w(ﾟДﾟ)w ! Smart hack. Thanks ^_^